# Set fake duration on h264 video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, metadata, h.264

I have a script that fetches multiple chunks of a video from one place and streams it as a single video to other place (to Kodi player).

Everything seems to work fine except one thing that bothers me, the player doesn't seem to know how long the video is, therefore the total duration increments as the video plays.

I do know the duration of the video from an xml file that contains a link to all the chunks, but I don't know how to write that in the metadata of the first chunk.

The video codec is h264, but I'm not sure if it is wrapped in some container, like mp4.

Here is the `ffmpeg -i` output for the first chunk:

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.1.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mpegts @ 0x7fc3c6000000] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
Input #0, mpegts, from '/Users/ibra/Desktop/daTgXic4JOI.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:17.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1220 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:1[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 150 kb/s
```

And here is a messy screenshot of the file opened in a hex editor:
https://www.evernote.com/l/AWlILw5PcmVEl4fSFitOfS2M8Wzy1WTVSZc

Any suggestions of how to insert the video duration in the metadata of the first chunk?

I cannot download the all the chunks and then concat in a single file because this will take too much time and the streaming must be instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container format is mpegts. There is no standard way to encode a duration in mpegts (or h.264 for that matter). So whatever you do will be proprietary. You could write it to the ID3 metaadata, but then kodi would need to be modified to handle this.

Comment: How unfortunate. Thank you for your answer.